# Set default font and layout for OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice

How do I set OpenOffice's default font and layout? I have a font that I want it to use when I create a new document. In addition, I want new documents to appear as Web Layout.

I'm running OpenOffice.org 3.2.0 on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the Format menu and choose "Styles and Formatting" (or press F11).  Right click on the Default style select "Modify...".  Change your options accordingly (font, etc.).  Also, set Web Layout from the View menu as you like.

Then, from the File menu, choose "Templates", then "Save...".

Select "My Templates" from the Categories box on the left, then "default_document" from the Templates box on the right (even if it's selected, click on it anyway).  Then hit OK and that should do it.